# VBA Macro to remove line with Zero figure

Tags: excel, vba

I want to enhance my current VBA Macro which exports data from one place to another by removing all rows that have Zero Amount in column G. Can someone show me what VBA script i need to add in my current script to do this?

Here is my script now:

```
Sub ExportFees()
'
' ExportFees Macro
' Mgt Fee Import
'

    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = Worksheets("Tradar Import").Range("Y8")
    Columns("A:W").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\\BET-SYD-SVR01\Betashares\Ops\Tradar Import\FEE001\" & Filename, FileFormat _
        :=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

[Original Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQfmu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you set a range reference to the data then you can use `Range.AutoFilter` to filter the data and `Range.Copy` to copy the filtered data to a destination range.

```
Sub ExportFees()
'
' ExportFees Macro
' Mgt Fee Import
'

    Dim Filename As String

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd
    DataRange.AutoFilter

    Filename = Worksheets("Tradar Import").Range("Y8")
    Workbooks.Add

    DataRange.Copy Destination:=Range("A1")

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\\BET-SYD-SVR01\Betashares\Ops\Tradar Import\FEE001\" & Filename, FileFormat _
        :=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. It works.

I noticed the autofilter leaves it filters format. Is there some type of code to add in the macro to undo the Autofilter once the file is created?

Comment: I updated my answer.  You just have to use `DataRange.AutoFilter` with no parameters.